# use wkhtmltopdf without creating file

Tags: java, wkhtmltopdf

All is in the question. In java I have created a process which will execute wkhtmltopdf but I need to give to an output file and I want to create the pdf and have it in a buffer without creating the file and then read it. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wkhtmltopdf can be used as an executable or as a library. As a library you can get the output into memory. A snipplet from a c++ Wrapper for it:

```
if(wkhtmltopdf_convert(conv))
{
    // Get Output as buffer
   const unsigned char *data = nullptr;
   size_t length = wkhtmltopdf_get_output(conv, &data);
   ....
}
```